Unable to find solution for a certain sorting scenario
I have a scenario where I regularly need to maintain records in a table that defines workflow order definitions to add and remove stages which puts the IDs in a non-deal order (cant change the IDs after the fact).
I need an order by (or other) method to select the records and show the order they will execute to easily manage them but cant find a solution though believe there would be an obvious one I am missing. NULL in parent_id is the start of the worflow.
Example Simple Records:
id  strategy_id stage   parent_id
74  15  REMINDER_01 NULL
99  15  WARNING_06  74
76  15  WARNING_05  75
91  15  WARNING_08  76
78  15  WARNING_07  91
75  15  DEMAND_01   99

Order I need them returned to easily work on them and see the order:
id  strategy_id stage   parent_id
74  15  REMINDER_01 NULL
99  15  WARNING_06  74
75  15  DEMAND_01   99
76  15  WARNING_05  75
91  15  WARNING_08  76
78  15  WARNING_07  91

I have tried searching for a solution based on the concept but believe I am using the wrong terminology so not getting anything that is a match.

Use the recursive method with database to generate your solution. I have used Postgres with version 16 to generate solution. Same solution will work for the MySql as well.
Working Query:
WITH RECURSIVE orderWorkflow AS (
  SELECT id, strategy_id, stage, parent_id, 0 AS level
  FROM mytable
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t.id, t.strategy_id, t.stage, t.parent_id, wo.level + 1 AS level
  FROM mytable t
  INNER JOIN orderWorkflow wo ON t.parent_id = wo.id
)
SELECT id, strategy_id, stage, parent_id
FROM orderWorkflow
ORDER BY level, id;

Working Demo:
https://dbfiddle.uk/rJvttCql

Hi Akshay, Thanks for taking the time to create the in depth and clear answer. This solved my scenario and I have accepted the answer.
